# How to connect docker containers to physical local network?

Tags: docker, dhcp-server

I have a automation script which runs clusters docker containers which are need to be in my local network. Right now i am manually collecting list of un-used IP address in an array and i am poping out for every docker containers one by one. Instead i need DHCP server to decide IP address for my docker containers. Is it possible? and how?

Comment: you said *"manually collecting list of un-used IP address in an array and i am poping out for every docker containers one by one"* are you assigning IP to new containers ?if yes , then , how are you doing it ?
elaborate please.

Comment: I am assigning my own IP address after running the docker container. which mean just like how we are assigning the ip address to our machine.`docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -d -it  vickyrajagopal/nginx /bin/sh -c "/sbin/ip addr add 192.10.20.30 dev eth0;  bash"` so in this NET_ADMIN is to get admin privilege for `/sbin/ip addr add 192.10.20.30 dev eth0` and `vickyrajagopal/nginx`is my image. just inspect the created docker container. You can find the ip and every thing. If configuration is not proper then change it. for my requirment this configuration is more than enough.@OvigzHero

Comment: @OvigzHero Please do answer for my question too. i just need to assign IP by DHCP. is there any docker functionality there or any trick to associate docker with DHCP?